# Passing parameters to $resource (using @)

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

In my controller:

```
UserResource.find({ userId: userId }, function (records) {
                            $scope.user= records;
                        });
```

In my resource:

```
angular.module("main_k").
    factory("main_k.service.resource.Order", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
        return $resource("../rest/user/:action?:identification", {
            action: "@userId",
            identification: "identification51854"
        }, { find: { method: "GET"}
     });
    }]);
```

The problem is that the userId gets appended to the url instead of to be filled in, into action. Identification is filled in correctly.
What am I doing wrong in order to pass the userId value?

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda weird. When you do GET request you need to set the original variable name `:action` instead of `userId` if you want to interpolate it the path.

```
UserResource.find({
    action: userId
}, function (records) {
    $scope.user = records;
});
```